# Mismatch of opening and closing quote of href while dealing with jsp session value

Tags: javascript, jsp, anchor, href

I am working on a jsp application. I have an `User` object in my `session`.
From jsp I can acess the following value successfully -

```
userType = ${USER.type};
editPermission = ${USER.hasPermission['editPermission'];  //case 1.
```

Here `hasPermission` is `Map<String, Boolean>`. In **case 1** it returns true/false. But When I use it in a `<a>` it doesn't works properly. It seems the `href` attribute quote ('') confilicts with the `'editPermission'` quotes. Please can any one help me how to solve this problem?

```
<a href="#tab" onclick="window.location.href='.../home.do?tbNam=all&userType=${USER.type}&editPermission=${USER.hasPermission['editPermission']}';">All</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing the '}' closing bracket after this "${USER.hasPermission['editPermission']' ". Check that

Comment: @Ramkumar, thanks for your finding. Here it was a typos which I already have fixed. But in my code there was the '}'

Comment: you can use escape sequence "\". Please check this
onclick="window.location.href=\".../home.do?tbNam=all&userType=${USER.type}&editPermission=${USER.hasPermission['editPermission']}\";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable does not evaluate in this context.

Do like this

```
<a href="#tab" onclick="window.location.href='.../home.do?tbNam=all&userType=' + ${USER.type} + '&editPermission=' + ${USER.hasPermission['editPermission']} + ';'>All</a>
```